# Convert year from unicode format to python's datetime format

Tags: python, numpy, python-datetime

I have only year parameter as input in the following manner:

```
2014,2015,2016
```

I want to convert each element from my list into python's datetime format. Is it possible to do this kind of things if the only given parameter is the year ?

Answer (score 0):

Just set month and day manually to 1

```
 from datetime import date
 YearLst = [2014,2015,2016]
 map(lambda t: date(t, 1, 1),YearLst)
```